# having error line when putting jquery code online

Tags: php, jquery

Planning to put an scrollable  gallery online with **lightbox**. I have encounter an error, one of my code have **unexpected " : ", expected one of: "}" , " " ,** ATTR

Using CMS Made Simple.
for cmsms error, it display

> At line 702 in file /xxx/xxx/public_html/lib/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php

This is the code i plan to put on my website.
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

I will post my error here and my full script after that.

**Error code.**

```
jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function(){
            if(jQuery("#gallery").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")){
                jQuery("#gallery").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });
```

**Full code.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){ 

    // Gallery
    if(jQuery("#gallery").length){

        // Fancybox
        jQuery("#gallery li a").fancybox({
            'titleShow'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
        });

        // Variables aren't use properly due to Webkit
        var totalImages = jQuery("#gallery > li").length, 
            imageWidth = jQuery("#gallery > li:first").outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round(jQuery("#gallery-wrap").width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery").width(totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function(){
            if(jQuery("#gallery").position().left < 0 && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")){
                jQuery("#gallery").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function(){
            if(jQuery("#gallery").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")){
                jQuery("#gallery").animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

appreciate for all help. 
thanks

Comment: if there is no solution for it, is there any recommendation for image and video thumbnail scroller code that download? i wish i have something like http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be using smarty, and the problem is that smarty is getting confused with the opening/closing brackets {}. Try to surround the script with smarty's {literal} tag, ie.:

```
{literal}
<script.....

</script>
{/literal}
```

Also, if you're using smarty 3, it will probably work without the literal tag, by just adding a space after every "{" and before every "}"

```
jQuery("#gallery").animate({ left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px" });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your error is here:

> jQuery("#gallery").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});

From [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) it seems that the correct synthax is .animate({left: imageWidth + "px"});

Did you change anything from the original example? There are plenty of free coverflow / content flowlibraries you can use for your animated gallery. I am only familiar with javascript ones, here is one I used recently and was quite good http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/